# Seting Up auto mailer for google sheet data

Tags: email, google-sheets, filtering

I have a google sheet in which data flows from google sheet and updates the status of various activities in the form of Yes and No. I want to set up an auto mailer specifically for Pending activities (having status as No). Can anyone help with filtering script along with mailing the filtered table in body or as attachment.

Tried multiple other scripts but too complex for me to identify the issue with each query

Comment: The question is addressing several aspects of a complex system: linked sheets (details unknown - possible tracking issues), automailer; filtered table; sending table in mail or as attachment. I suggest that you  focus on a single issue and provide sufficient information about that aspect of the scenario that will allow users to assist.